# how to make af:inputText resizible in adf?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have An inputText that i'm trying to Make Resizible

and i've put it in AF:PanelStrechLayout but it didn't work

and this my code

```
 <af:panelStretchLayout dimensionsFrom="auto" >
     <f:facet name="center" >
     <af:panelGroupLayout >
        <af:inputText rendered="#{bindings.commentType1.inputValue eq 'out'}"   autoSubmit="true" simple="true" value="#{bindings.newCommentValue.inputValue}" />
        <af:inputText rendered="#{bindings.commentType1.inputValue eq 'mile'}"  autoSubmit="true" simple="true" value="#{bindings.newCommentValue1.inputValue}" />
     </af:panelGroupLayout >
      </f:facet>

    </af:panelStretchLayout>
```

im also have an inputText in popup that don't resize depend on the Text Length and the text is truncated

and this is the code for it

```
<af:inputText disabled="true"  value="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.inputValue}" simple="true" rendered="#{bindings.commentType1.inputValue eq 'out'}"
                      required="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.hints.mandatory}"
                      columns="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.hints.displayWidth}" 
                      maximumLength="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.hints.precision}"
                      shortDesc="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.hints.tooltip}" id="it39">
            <f:validator binding="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.validator}"/>
        </af:inputText>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADF, to have a resizable input you should use the **af:richTextEditor** component instead of your *af:inputText*.

In your case :

```
<af:richTextEditor disabled="true"  value="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.inputValue}" simple="true" rendered="#{bindings.commentType1.inputValue eq 'out'}"
              required="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.hints.mandatory}"
              shortDesc="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.hints.tooltip}" id="it39">
    <f:validator binding="#{bindings.CrOuputComments.validator}"/>
</af:richTextEditor>
```

Comment: af:richTextEditor is not strictly comparable to and interchangeable with af:inputText, since the former is meant for rich HTML text.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is to set styleClass="AFStretchWidth" on the af:inputText tag like so:

```
<af:inputText rendered="#{bindings.commentType1.inputValue eq 'out'}"   autoSubmit="true" simple="true" value="#{bindings.newCommentValue.inputValue}" />
```

The previous answer although it works is an overkill, since richTextEditor although a plain text input field, is not comparable to inputText since it can also accept HTML formatting tags for rich text content and has higher heavy heap consumption on the page.

**Further update based on MrAdibou's comment:** If drag resize handle is needed, set rows attribute on af:inputText to a value of 2 or more which converts the input field to a text area. Text area control gets the drag handle in the bottom right corner in most browsers.

Comment: AFStretchWidth will not make the inputText "resizable" which is OP's question.

Comment: If OP needs resize handle for drag sizing, then rows attribute does the trick by converting input text to a HTML textArea control. Edited the answer to include this too for others who stumble here with the same problem.